Kamal - ERROR (SSHKit::Command::Failed): Exception while executing on host *YOUR_IP_ADDRESS_HERE*
Attempting to run and deploy the basic Ruby On Rails 8.0 tutorial project, details here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
I have followed the instructions, including exporting KAMAL_REGISTRY_PASSWORD, which I have confirmed with the command echo $KAMAL_REGISTRY_PASSWORD
After running the command bin/kamal setup I get this error at the end of the process:
Finished in 5.431 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  Finished all in 8.0 seconds
Releasing the deploy lock...
  Finished all in 19.0 seconds
  ERROR (SSHKit::Command::Failed): Exception while executing on host *YOUR_IP_ADDRESS_HERE*: mkdir exit status: 1
mkdir stdout: Nothing written
mkdir stderr: zsh:1: no matches found: [2024-12-23T15:56:01Z]

When running the command with -verbose the following error is displayed:
/Users/YOURNAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/sshkit-1.23.2/lib/sshkit/command.rb:97:in `exit_status='
/Users/YOURNAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/sshkit-1.23.2/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:185:in `execute_command'
/Users/YOURNAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/sshkit-1.23.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
<internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
/Users/YOURNAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/sshkit-1.23.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `create_command_and_execute'
/Users/YOURNAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/sshkit-1.23.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:80:in `execute'
/Users/YOURNAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/kamal-2.4.0/lib/kamal/cli/build.rb:156:in `block in pull_on_hosts'
/Users/YOURNAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/sshkit-1.23.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `instance_exec'
/Users/YOURNAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/sshkit-1.23.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `run'
/Users/YOURNAME/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/kamal-2.4.0/lib/kamal/sshkit_with_ext.rb:118:in `block (2 levels) in execute'

This code may also be relevant from the failed deployment:
 DEBUG [1d3aeb7a] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p .kamal && echo [2024-12-23T19:04:15Z] [32644073+YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME@users.noreply.github.com] Pulled image with version 786d9916973f2df387d7687459058413355b4182 >> .kamal/deployment_test-audit.log on YOUR_IP_ADDRESS
 DEBUG [1d3aeb7a] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p .kamal && echo [2024-12-23T19:04:15Z] [32644073+YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME@users.noreply.github.com] Pulled image with version 786d9916973f2df387d7687459058413355b4182 >> .kamal/deployment_test-audit.log
 DEBUG [1d3aeb7a]      zsh:1: no matches found: [2024-12-23T19:04:15Z]
  Finished all in 10.9 seconds
Releasing the deploy lock...
 DEBUG [69679b74] Running /usr/bin/env rm .kamal/lock-deployment_test/details && rm -r .kamal/lock-deployment_test on YOUR_IP_ADDRESS
 DEBUG [69679b74] Command: /usr/bin/env rm .kamal/lock-deployment_test/details && rm -r .kamal/lock-deployment_test
 DEBUG [69679b74] Finished in 0.074 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  Finished all in 18.6 seconds

It seems to be successfully pushing to a Docker Hub repository, but isn't completing the deployment process on my server.
These are the only alterations I've made to the default deploy.yml file.
# Name of your application. Used to uniquely configure containers.
service: deployment_test

# Name of the container image.
image: *YOUR_DOCKER_USERNAME*/deployment-test

# Deploy to these servers.
servers:
  web:
    - *YOUR_IP_ADDRESS_HERE*
  # job:
  #   hosts:
  #     - 192.168.0.1
  #   cmd: bin/jobs

# Enable SSL auto certification via Let's Encrypt and allow for multiple apps on a single web server.
# Remove this section when using multiple web servers and ensure you terminate SSL at your load balancer.
#
# Note: If using Cloudflare, set encryption mode in SSL/TLS setting to "Full" to enable CF-to-app encryption.
proxy:
  ssl: true
  host: *YOUR WEBSITE URL WITH DNS SET UP (e.g. deployme.com)*

# Credentials for your image host.
registry:
  # Specify the registry server, if you're not using Docker Hub
  # server: registry.digitalocean.com / ghcr.io / ...
  username: *YOUR_DOCKER_USERNAME_HERE*

  # Always use an access token rather than real password when possible.
  password:
    - KAMAL_REGISTRY_PASSWORD

When asking ChatGPT, it said it was something to do with how Zsh was interpreting square brackets [] but I tried using bash as it suggested and the same error occurred.
I can't see anything I've done wrong in terms of following the steps on the tutorial linked above.
However I am new to both Docker and RoR, apologies if I've missed something super obvious here. Any help would be hugely appreciated.
VERSIONS USED
Server is a 2GB Linode VPS running Ubuntu
Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Ruby 3.3.6
Rails 8.0.1
Docker version 27.4.1, build b9d17eaebb


mkdir exit status: 1 -- indicates a permissions issue on the host.  Unfortunately, the tutorial seems a little light on what is needed for host permissions. What user are you using to run bin/kamal setup?

I'm running the bin/kamal setup command from my default MacOS user on localhost, then it prompts for password entry for my server during the deployment process which is root@*YOUR_IP_ADDRESS_HERE*

I've done that now - 100% confirmed I can run mkdir directly from the command line after logging into the server with the details root@*YOUR_IP_ADDRESS_HERE*

Just ran that now - have updated the original post with updated error message. ChatGPT is still saying the same thing about square brackets regarding this issue, even with the new information.

Apologies for that oversight - I've just updated the original post with more code which I believe shows the failing mkdir, if this is not accurate/clear I can put the entire deployment log on a pastebin if that is easier.

Here is a Pastebin link to the full anonymised bin/kamal setup -v log: https://pastebin.com/mBhL4xM9

The deployment is failing in the pull_hosts method, when it calls execute *KAMAL.auditor.record("Pulled image with version #{KAMAL.config.version}"), verbosity: :debug. This looks like the first time it is trying to access the audit log and it is failing -- probably while trying to construct the audit log file path. I'd be tempted create an issue -- logging should not blow things up.

Never trust ChatGPT. But you need to fill in the YOUR_NAME and YOUR_USERNAME stuff. Have you done that? And then connect to the host and do an ls -al /Users/ and check the permissions. You can adjust them with chmod
